# Set max & min xAxis value for scrolling

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstock chart that displays sensor data using ajax request.
Everytime the extremes change on the xAxis I am loading the relevant data from the server and display it.
On the page I also have two dateTime controls to select start and end date of the period you want to watch the data from.

Now I have the problem that when I set start to 11/28/2012 and end also to 11/28/2012 and I scroll (minimum range is 1 day) the user is able to scroll out of the selected range which I am trying to prohibit.

I couldn't find any examples or solutions that work.

I tried setting the chart.navigator.xAxis.min and max, also tried to set chart.xAxis.min and max but this isn't working...

Take a look yourself  here:
http://carbocount.wikidot.com/project:products:visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem on my own.
In the `afterSetExtremes` event I checked the extremes using `e.dataMin` and `e.dataMax` if the range is between the selected time period. It not I reset the extremes:

```
        // if the user tries to zoom outside of the selected time period
        // cancel the event and reset extremes
        var extremesReset = false;

        if (e.dataMin < plotStart.getTime()) {
            e.dataMin = plotStart.getTime();
            extremesReset = true;
        }
        if (e.dataMax > plotEnd.getTime()) {
            e.dataMax = plotEnd.getTime();
            extremesReset = true;
        }

        var chart = $('#plot').highcharts();

        if (extremesReset)
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.dataMin, e.dataMax);
```